# How to attach an attachement in webtocase without using controller?

Tags: attachment, web2case

I need to add an attachment while creating the case . I mean , while submitting the webform the attachment should be added along with the case creation. Can anyone please tell me how to do this ??

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 2):

This idea - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrhfAAC is expected to be delivered shortly as per the latest comments from project management.

As of now, the only option you have is to build a custom process and create a case and attachment via Salesforce API from the Webform on the site.